# How to export cards to email in Trello

Tags: trello, export

I am using Trello, but not everyone is a fan in my organisation. So a wanted to ask if it is possible to send cards as an email/task to another persons outlook/exchange account.

I make my project, but someone else needs to perform the task → I send the card to this person and he uses his own system to further follow up the card. When the card is finished, he can send me another notification, and I can place the card in the right (done)-column.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think that using the "Email to Card" function might help you out.

1. Open the card you want to share with your co-worker.
2. Click "Share and more" in the bottom of the right column.
3. Click "Email for this card"
4. Copy and send this email address to your co-worker

Anything emailed into that address will show up as a comment on that card.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your best option is to use the print function on the Trello Card to export it as a PDF, in combination with the feature mentioned above "Email to Card" by including that in CC of the email you want to send:

[image]

Then right-click on the exported PDF and go to Send to > Mail Recipient:

[image]

And an Email will be created to which you can add to CC: field, however, you will have to ask your colleagues to do replay all when they want to respond.

[image]